# Cannot search on a particular index

Tags: thinking-sphinx

Model:

```
class TechRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  define_index do
  ...
    indexes  :hot_request
    indexes :status_id, :as => :current_status_id
  ...
    has :hot_request , :as => :hot_request
    set_property :delta => true
  end
```

DB:

```
hot_request - tinyint(1)
```

When I execute the controller code-

```
@query_string = '(@hot_request 1)(@current_status_id 1 | 2 | 3)'
@tech_requests = TechRequest.search @query_string, :match_mode => :extended
```

the following error is thrown up:

```
ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError: index tech_request_core,tech_request_delta: query error: no field 'tech_hot_request' found in schema
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:392:in 'populate'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:508:in 'call'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:508:in 'retry_on_stale_index'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:379:in 'populate'
        from D:/Current/TechAssistTest/vendor/plugins/thinking-sphinx/lib/thinking_sphinx/search.rb:167:in 'method_missing'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:302:in 'output_value'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:151:in 'eval_input'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:263:in 'signal_status'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:147:in 'eval_input'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:146:in 'eval_input'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:70:in 'start'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:69:in 'catch'
        from D:/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/irb.rb:69:in 'start'
        from D:/ruby/bin/irb:13
```

The search works fine when I use `hot_request` as an attribute. The
search also works fine when I use `@query_string = '(@current_status_id 1 | 2 | 3)'`.

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into similar looking problems - there are two possible reasons why this errors that I can see.  First is that according to http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=2103 you can use an sql column as a field or an attribute but not both (without cloning it).  The other, which had me baffled for a while, is that you may need to specify the type - so if hot_request is actually an integer, you probably need to have something like

indexes hot_request :as => hr, :type => :integer

or you get that cryptic error message

Hope this helps someone ...